# Disabling undo/redo in an HTML input field

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, undo-redo

I am using asp.net input fields and they automatically provide undo/redo functionality. I am using JavaScript to format the value of the input field, however this ruins the undo/redo history.

- Is there a way to disable the undo/redo feature?

  or
- Is there a way to interact with the undo/redo history to add the correct values?

Comment: Doesn't the `onchange` event fire when undoing or redoing things? Maybe that's a way to hook into it

Comment: I recently discovered that on Chrome, the textareas on http://jsfiddle.net lose their undo history when clicking "Run". Don't yet know how, but might be of interest.

Comment: Maybe you could attach a keydown/keyup/keypress listener to the input field and issue e.preventDefault() on events that have the 'control' or 'command' keys pressed (ie. suppress Ctrl-z).

Comment: @Jonathan that won't catch e.g. when the context menu is used

Answer (score 3):

Using JavaScript, try replacing the text field with a new one and *then* setting the value.  New field, new undo buffer, right?

jQuery:

```
$('#theTextField').after('<textarea id="theTextField2"></textarea>').remove();
$('#theTextField2').attr('id','theTextField');
```

Comment: It will have all bounds event lost. Perhaps utilizing `.clone(true)` might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with this idea to remove the Undo/Redo to an input field using DOM manipulation and cloning, but make sure that the input is inside a parent node, this approach appends the newly **cloned** input field

I call this method on "onchange" event of the input... this is just a hack though.

```
function decup(e){

    let new_ =  e.target.cloneNode();
        let parent_N = e.target.parentNode;
            e.target.remove();
            parent_N.appendChild(new_);                     
        console.log(parent_N);

}
```