# Clear UNDO history of events in browser with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, undo, undo-redo

I have a CodeMirror instance written in Javascript that acts as a code editor. I load the code for the procedure the user selects..when the user selects one procedure then another I just call the set the value to the code of that procedure. When I do this and the user clicks CTRL+Z or right click, undo it brings back the previous procedure. I need to clear the undo history when I call set value..can't find out how to do this have looked all over..any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling undo/redo in an HTML input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453927/disabling-undo-redo-in-an-html-input-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about clearHistory() . it works for me. call it when user selects a procedure.

```
editor.clearHistory()
```

or you can completely disable the undo feature by using "undoDepth" in codemirror configuration

```
undoDepth : 0 ,
```